# Semiautomatic rename of files according to pattern?

Tags: linux, windows, freebsd, rename, batch-rename

I have a lot of files and directories named similar to `[Origin]Description[Techinfo]`.

Sometimes, brackets can be round brackets instead of square brackets, or spaces between the parts. How can I rename (ideally recursively) the files that I get something like

*script or function* `[Origin]Description[Techinfo]` ---> `Description[Origin][Techinfo]` ?

I can access the NAS via SSH, it runs FreeBSD (FreeNAS). Or I could do it via a client (Linux or Windows).

Comment: You have to individuate each single possibility to create a _regex_. The ones with spaces will be the most difficult because you cannot know in advance if a space belongs to the description or to the _Techinfo_. But it will be a secondary problem. Is the full list Are a full list of descriptions or of TechInfo available somewhere?

Comment: I'm seeing bash in your future, perhaps awk, sed, perl...

Comment: @Hastur: No, no full lists. We are talking about media files, with arbitrary naming.

I am looking for something which identifies the three blocks, based on the brackets, and just swaps from ABC to BAC.

Answer (score 0):

Windows, powershell V2, [Origin]Description[Techinfo] -> Description[Origin][Techinfo]:

```
powershell (ls -Re -Fo -Fi "*[*")^|%{$f=$_.Name -split('[\]\[ \)\(]');$r='\'+$f[2]+'['+$f[1]+']['+$f[3]+']';[IO.File]::Move($_.FullName,$_.DirectoryName+$r)}
```

Comment: I am a complete rookie with powershell, so I just copied and pasted it and ran it in a test directory. This is what I got:

'Exception at call of "Move" with 2 argument(s):  "An empty filename is not allowed.
Parameter name: sourceFileName"
In line:1 character:109
+ ... ']['+$f[3]+']';[IO.File]::Move($_.FullName,$_.DirectoryName+$r)}
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException'

Comment: @emk2203 run as command or script?